# How to encrypt keys in Android application

Tags: android, encryption, public-key-encryption, android-proguard

My app uses keys to authenticate and communicate with server, we need way to encrypt the keys or hide the keys to prevent it get access when we de-compile the APK.

I used the pro-guard to encrypt, but it did not work as expected. Here is the way i used pro-guard,

in proguard-android.txt i updated below content.

```
-dontwarn com.serveraccess.**
-dontwarn weborb.**
-keep class weborb.** {*;}
-keep class com.serveraccess.** {*;}
```

This is not working, please help me